# IEEE Conference style citation

Tags: bibtex, ieee-style

I am starting to need to some help with references. I'm writing a paper using IEEE citation style and I'm trying to refer to a conference paper. These citations should follow this style: http://libguides.murdoch.edu.au/content.php?pid=144623&sid=1229936

The paper I'm trying to cite: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2347587

I used the sites tool to get the BibTeX citation (three lines removed though):

```
@inproceedings{Valtchanov:2012:EDC:2347583.2347587,
 author = {Valtchanov, Valtchan and Brown, Joseph Alexander},
 title = {Evolving Dungeon Crawler Levels with Relative Placement},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the Fifth International C* Conference on Computer Science and     Software Engineering},
 series = {C3S2E '12},
 year = {2012},
 isbn = {978-1-4503-1084-0},
 location = {Montreal, Quebec, Canada},
 pages = {27--35},
 numpages = {9},
 publisher = {ACM},
 address = {New York, NY, USA},
 keywords = {evolutionary computation, level generation, procedural content generation},
}
```

And on writelatex.com I use:

```
\bibliography{references.bib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

It creates a reference that looks like this:

V. Valtchanov and J. A. Brown, "Evolving dungeon crawler levels with relative
placement," in Proceedings of the Fifth International C* Conference on
Computer Science and Software Engineering, ser. C3S2E '12. New York,
NY, USA: ACM, 2012, pp. 27-35.

Which is really nice, but it's not completely correct. Notice how it doesn't mention the publication location and date, not the conference location.

(Or it's possible that I'm missunderstanding the whole thing)

Comment: Not all information available is printed. The IEEE provides (or whoever maintains it) a style. You should not worry too much.

Comment: Thank you both, I have to let it go for now then and consult the professor about how important the citation style is.

Answer (score 6):

The only way I can see for you to use the `IEEEtran` bibliography style *and* to satisfy your university's apparent requirement to list both the location and date of the event (and to have these two pieces of information typeset in italics!) is to include the location and date information directly in the `booktitle` field.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Valtchanov:2012:EDC:2347583.2347587,
 author = {Valtchanov, Valtchan and Brown, Joseph Alexander},
 title = {Evolving Dungeon Crawler Levels with Relative Placement},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the Fifth International C* Conference on Computer Science 
    and Software Engineering, Montreal, Quebec, Canada, June 27--29, 2012},
 series = {C3S2E '12},
 year = {2012},
 isbn = {978-1-4503-1084-0},
 pages = {27--35},
 numpages = {9},
 publisher = {ACM},
 address = {New York, NY, USA},
 keywords = {evolutionary computation, level generation, procedural content generation},
} 
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Johannes just said, this is the `IEEEtran` bibliography style expected behavior.  You either completely embrace it, or modify it so it fits your needs... but it will not longer be IEEE compliant.

Comment: I was hoping that someone would say that I missed something obvious that would fix it. I will have to consult my professor about how important the citation style is, if it explicitly has to look the way it does in the link.

Thank you.

Comment: There's a third option: Modify the contents of the `booktitle` field so that it includes the additional pieces of information required by the OP's university.

Answer (score 0):

For IEEE, use the address instead of location

Comment: For me, this has some unacceptable effects: 1.) no comma between booktitle and location, 2.) a weird colon between location and organization.